# CasperJS on NodeJS - cannot find module casper

Tags: node.js, installation, phantomjs, casperjs

Im currently trying to get Casperjs working on my Nodejs discord bot. But everytime i want to test it (with the example provided by the casperjs documentation)

```
var casper = require("casper").create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Everytime i wanted to start real coding im confroted with "cannot find module casper". How can i solve this ?

i already tried some solutions from stackoverflow, but the all seem to be outdated/ i used them wrong.

i also read that i need phantomjs for casper (so i did npm install phantom) but dont know if i need to do more with it. Later on i also read that casper can be used alone now. I followed the Quickstart guide on the casper.js website but didn´t manage to make it work.

Thank you for your Answers !

Comment: `npm install casper` ?

Comment: Yes I did it and can find casperjs in my node-modules folder

Comment: My bad, package name is `casperjs`, not `casper`. You should do `npm install casperjs`

Comment: How do you run the sample script?

Comment: I run it with npm run test wich starts my main.js

Answer (score 2):

CasperJS is not compatible with node.js, it is not a module, npm is just another distribution channel for it. You must run its scripts with CasperJS' own binary.

Answer (score 0):

CasperJS nor PhantomJS can be ran directly from nodejs. 
You need some kind of wrapper in order to run it from node. Most of the time it consist of a sub process creation that runs the actual CapserJS script. Then you must wait for the return code in order to decide what's next in the nodejs part.

In the case of CasperJS there is the SpookyJS Library that could meet your needs.

https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS